# Partitioning the appropriate error term in a repeated measures R

Tags: r, anova, interaction, linear-model

Basically I have a repeated measures experiment with two reward levels and two speed levels. Every trial participant can be randomly presented with highReward*slowSpeed or lowReward*fastSpeed etc., resulting in a 2 x 2 design. I am not completely sure when it is appropriate to use either of the models below:

```
model <- lme(value ~ reward*speed, random = (~reward+speed|participant),data)
```

adding the participant:reward:speed error term to the model

```
model <- lme(value ~ reward*speed, random = (~reward*speed|participant),data)
```

When it is appropriate to add the participant:reward:speed error term to the model?